# The opposite of reclined?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm aware of the difference between [Prone vs. Supine vs. Prostrate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prone-supine-prostrate-usage-differences), but I'm trying to find the opposite of the related word 'reclined'.

Every web or dictionary search brings up 'upright' as the antonym for reclined. That's not what I mean.

Where I envisaged a reclined person (on their back/supine but propped up), I'm trying to find the word for *lying on one's front* in the prone position also propped up.

A good example would be the stereotype of Romans eating on their stomach:

[image: modern representation of Roman people lying on their front around a table of food and eating from it]

Or this person reading while resting on a pillow:

[image: Asian man lying on his front reading manga, propped up by a small cushion]

Both pictures show them propped up, like a reclined person is, whether by pillows or use of their arms.

If I were to use it in a sentence, it might be:

> Derrek's partner reclined on the sunlounger, in contrast Derrek <word>ed by the pool.

I don't want to use the word prone, as I'm not using the word supine; 'prone' would feel out of place. Prone also implies to me that their face is pointed directly down to the floor or close to it, in much the way that Supine implies to me facing directly upward.

Comment: Perhaps "pronate", which has the meanings of "place in a prone position" and "assume a prone position" as well as the meanings relating to rotation of the arms or feet. (see https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pronate).

Comment: @peter please post that as an answer !

Comment: You mean _lying on one's front_!

Comment: @KateBunting I'm not lying though  not sure how that slipped by

Comment: Your example sentence appears wrong, Derrek's partner was supine while reclining; Derrek himself lay prone (which I guess might be an answer).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not sure what about my sentence you think is wrong (or how your suggestion fixes it?) But if supine is confusing you (and possibly others) I can edit the sentence to be simpler.

Comment: "*Lying on one's front*" is not the most idiomatic term ; "*lying on one's belly**" is the current one : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lying+on+one%27s+belly%2Clying+on+one%27s+front&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clying%20on%20one%20%27s%20belly%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH sadly neither fit my example sentence

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prone) has "prone" as a verb. But the OP seems to have an irrational prejudice against the term.

Comment: @StuartF irrational OP here, the verb listed is for either a medical term or combined with 'out' to mean "to lie flat on one's stomach on the ground" - but I'm not talking about lying *flat*. Have a look at those images, they aren't lying flat.

Comment: You are not looking for the opposite of *recline*.  You are looking for the opposite of *supine*.

Comment: @EllieK what makes you think that?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Recline is a verb. It's opposite is not upright.  It's opposite is *rise* or perhaps *stand up*.  A word describing the position of the people in your illustration would not be a verb.  I think *prone* answers your question.  Those people are *prone* with their faces *lifted off the floor*.  The people on their sides are not *reclining*.  They are *reclined*.

Comment: @EllieK looks like I messed that up before, it's fixed now.

Comment: @EllieK On airplanes, the wording is that you can __recline__ your seat (tilt it back) or __return your seat to an upright position__ (tilt it forward). If there were a better word or phrase for it, they would have it.

Comment: @Mitch - I try my best not to be pedantic.  In your example the verb *return* would function as the opposite of *recline*.  *Recline your seat to the laid back position* Vs *Return your seat to the upright position.*  The issue, of course, is that *return* is not the opposite of *recline*.  I do see the word upright in your sentence and I understand its relationship to the word *recline* but it is not an antonym.  *Upright* is the opposite of *laid back* in this case.

Comment: @EllieK I will not endeavor to impugn your pedanticity. You have made my point for me. 'Recline' doesn't have a convenient _single word_ opposite; the airlines all need to give a phrase as the opposite. The elementary school exercise of one-to-one antonyms works until it doesn't, and 'doesn't' happens for most words past a certain complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The word "pronate" has the meanings of "place in a prone position" and "assume a prone position" as well as meanings relating to rotation of the arms or feet. (see thefreedictionary.com/pronate).

Comment: Does that work in my example sentence?

Comment: It seems a bit formal for the suggested context.

Comment: @TobySpeight also "in contrast Derrek pronated by the pool." Just doesn't work

Comment: Yes, that's what I said - too formal.

Comment: @TobySpeight I was pointing out it doesn't make sense, not that it's 'too formal'. It's unusual for Pronate to be intransitive.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not great, and it’s not a perfect antonym, but how about *sprawl*?

“Derek sprawled by the pool.”

Comment: No. You can be sprawled on your back.

Comment: "Sprawled" also means spread out, rather than lying compactly.

Answer (score 0):

[Erect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erect). Erect: (a : vertical in position also : not spread out or decumbent an erect plant stem columns still erect in the ruins
b : standing up or out from the body erect hairs
c : characterized by firm or rigid straightness in bodily posture)